# Removing Luminosity from Colors in Plotly Express Boxplot

Tags: python, plot

I am creating box plots using Plotly Express in Python, and I want to remove the luminosity effect from the colors used in the plot. The default behavior seems to include varying luminosity, and I would like to set a single color without luminosity for each category in my box plot.

I've tried using the color_discrete_map parameter, but it doesn't seem to provide a straightforward way to remove the luminosity. Additionally, I couldn't find a relevant parameter in the Plotly Express documentation.

Is there a specific parameter or approach in Plotly Express that allows me to set a single color without luminosity for each category in a box plot? If not, are there any workarounds or alternative methods to achieve this?